# I'd like an external play button for this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this radio stream, and I wanna make a play button in an external area. Is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cstrpuid = 381022;
var cstrpwidth = "500";
var cstrpheight = "325";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.caster.fm/0070B7/widgets/player.js"></script>
<!--   DO NOT REMOVE THE LINKS BELOW, THEY  WILL BE HIDDEN (AND WILL HELP US A LOT)   -->
<a id="cstrplb" href="http://www.caster.fm/">Free Shoutcast Hosting</a><a id="cstrplb2" href="http://www.caster.fm/">Radio Stream Hosting</a>
<div id="cstrpdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Ask them instead of us. They wrote the thing

Comment: Agreed. This is third party software so your best guess would be to search whether they have some kind of API and if not, you might want to consider contacting their support.